# Dark mongoose magic: "Invalid argument to findOne"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

We have several nodejs daemons that make use of mongoose while sharing the same persistence layer (shared module containing the queries).

In one of these daemons (always the same one) we randomly (few times a week) get the following error from mongoose:

> mongoose: Invalid argument to findOne()

We've checked all queries and were not able to find out where this might come from. The errors call stack is different every time (**no specific mongoose call seems to cause this issue**) so we don't think this is specific to the business logic.

In order to do some debugging we added the following logging in case the error happens again:

```
log({
  // What mongoose checks (both false -> the error).
  isInstanceOfMQuery: conds instanceof mquery,
  isObject: mquery.utils.isObject(conds),
  // Trying to find out what this value is.
  conds,
  toString: Object.prototype.toString.call(conds)
  inspect: util.inspect(conds, { showHidden: true, depth: null, showProxy: true })
})
```

`conds` is the argument that mongoose is complaining about. log() will JSON.stringify() the whole thing.

This is one of the logs that resulted from this call:

```
{
  "isInstanceOfMQuery": false,
  "isObject": false,
  "conds": {},
  "toString": "[object Null]"
  "inspect": "{}",
}
```

Now this confuses me even more... how can conds be `{}` and `null` at the same time?!

Answers I'm looking for:

- How can I reproduce this kind of object that conds contains?
- How would you proceed with a bug that apparently happens randomly and seldomly?
- Is there more we could log in order to identify what kind of value conds has or where it comes from?

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: What version of Node are you running? I ask because I have seen this randomly with Node 7.4.0 but NOT with 6.9.2.

Comment: I saw some other really alarming stuff that looked like it was something to do with mysteriously null query objects in Node 7 with Mongoose 4, again did not observe with Node 6.

Comment: We've been running on the most current 7.x versions for quite some time now. I did a pull request a while ago to get mongoose working with it at all. The strange thing is that all the other daemons we have running with the same node version do not have this problem :-/
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: We saw that it happened very infrequently, but what we think are other effects of the same bug made it seem like actual query objects were disappearing, so we currently deem it too dangerous to run in production. I wonder what the difference is between this and your other Node 7 / Mongoose daemons.

Comment: We are looking at this problem in earnest now, trying to either understand it or get enough data to open an issue. Do you have any new observations?

Comment: We talked about it internally and decided to ignore this issue for the time being. It only happens once or twice a week and it doesn't cause any significant problems, therefore it's hard to justify investing anymore time into investigating this issue, sry :-/

Comment: Okay, thanks. We're investigating; it's really hard to reproduce, we opened https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5163 while we work on it, if you wouldn't mind posting your Node and Mongoose version details there, that'd be a help to us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a [node bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12411) with the PR to fix [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/12412). It's not yet included in a release.

It's not reliably reproducible since it seems to depend on pointers and v8's garbage collection. Just gotta wait for it to be fixed upstream.